# Mongo DB error: invalid operator: $search when doing $text search

Tags: mongodb

I've created an index with this:

```
db.MyCollection.ensureIndex({"field1": "text"})
```

and I'm running the following in Robomongo:

```
db.MyCollection.find({$text:{$search:"something"}})
```

and getting back this error:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $search", "code" : 10068 }
```

The docs seem to be pretty clear that I'm using the correct syntax: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/ . I'm using mongo version 2.4.9. Anyone know what the problem could be here?

Comment: The methods have changed between versions. For the 2.4.9 version of MongoDB, change the selected version in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/search-for-text/)

Comment: Thanks, write that up as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: No need. There actually is a "new In 2.6" statement right at the top of the [relevant manual page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/).

Comment: If you can honestly justify to me why you think it is necessary to clarify which documentation source to read by a post on stack overflow, I'll just accept that whatever answer is  given to that effect should be up-voted (no matter who it is). But I do believe the documentation is clear enough and you actually should remove your unanswered question. I cannot see how this helps, but convince me and I'll retract this.

Comment: I saw the note here: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/enable-text-search/ about version 2.4 so I assumed (wrongly) that the API in the manual would exist in 2.4.9. I just misread/skipped the one on the $text operator page. I could assume i'm the only person in the world who had this problem (since a google search for "invalid operator: $search" returned nothing relevant), but I would think my question might help someone someday - perhaps it already has since I have an upvote.

Comment: Helped me. Not sure why there is reluctance to throw up an answer @NeilLunn

Answer (score 1):

In mongo 2.6+ `$text` works as follows:

```
db.collection.insert({desc: "This is a string with text"});
db.collection.insert({desc:"This is a another string with Text"});
db.collection.insert({desc:"This is a another string with ext"});
db.collection.ensureIndex({"desc":"text"});
db.collection.find({
    $text:{
        $search:"text"
    }
});
```

This will gives output as :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553277a608b85f33165bf3e0"),
 "desc" : "This is a another string with Text" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5532779f08b85f33165bf3df"), 
"desc" : "This is a string with text" }
```

Also if you are using mongo version 2.4 then use following:

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex({"desc":"text"});
 db.collection.runCommand( "desc", { search: "Text"})
```