# mongodb text search: invalid operator: $search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, fulltext-index

Closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213007/mongo-db-error-invalid-operator-search-when-doing-text-search), but I'm using mongod version 3.2 which means its a different problem.

I created a text index:

```
> db.mycollection.createIndex({body:'text'})
```

Then I try to search it:

```
> db.mycollection.find({$text:{$search:'foo'}})
Error: error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $search", "code" : 10068 }
```

It [should](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#examples) work.  (changes to the $text operator for v3.2 shouldn't affect this.)  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your query and it runs perfectly fine. Try restarting database or even re-installing if possible.

Comment: Agreed. The query is correct and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had done a fresh uninstall / reinstall using [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), but it turned out an old databases had not been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an old database (created by mongod 2.4) that had survived the mongodb uninstall / reinstall process.  The [official doumentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) didn't mention it, but while uninstalling the old version, it was necessary to do:

```
sudo rm -r /data/db/*
```

(Perhaps because of how 2.4 was installed?) Deleting these files, and bringing my old data forward using the [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) commands worked.